# How to generate download link of s3 bucket content by using lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I usually put some object in schedule to my s3 bucket and wanna distribute them to team members.

So that I want to list the object and download link to achieve them without publicly exposing my s3 bucket.

I tried to generate direct s3 download link as follows. by referring to [this](https://github.com/rufuspollock/s3-bucket-listing) package.

```
  var s3_rest_url = BUCKET_URL;
  s3_rest_url += '?delimiter=/';
```

But it need to be s3 bucket publicly opened. and even if I tried to restrict access to specified public IP ranges it appeared that they changed in periodically so that it didn't work well.

My team members are not tech members and don't have any credentials and they are in certain VPC.

Can I achieve them by using lambda ?

Are there any materials of them ?

If someone has opinion or materials please let me know

Thanks

Comment: How do you want your "team members" to authenticate so that the solution knows they are authorized to access the files? Do they have AWS credentials? Will they "login" to an app? Or do you just want to give them a secret URL that works? More information, please.

Comment: I edited question, if further information is needed, please let me know. sorry for inconvenience, thanks

Answer (score 3):

In order to share private objects from a bucket, you can generate a [presigned url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) for it. This URL will be valid for certain period (max 7 days).

Yes, this can be done with a Lamdba, [example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/generate-presigned-url-modular-aws-sdk-javascript/).

Comment: example link no longer valid

Comment: @BoyePanthera Not an AWS official link, but here you can find another example: https://arpadt.com/articles/presigned-urls-in-node . I will try to correct the one from the example.

Comment: Example from the AWS developers blog using NodeJS: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/generate-presigned-url-modular-aws-sdk-javascript/